# How would you call a jQuery plugin as a method?

Tags: jquery, plugins

For example I have this plugin code:

```
jQuery.fn.keys = function(obj) {
    var keys = [];
    $.each(obj,function(i,elem) {
        keys.push(i);
    });
    return keys;
};
```

I'd like to apply this plugin in such a way:

```
var a = { 'a':1,'b':23,'c':43};
var b = $.keys(a); // should return ['a','b','c']
```

The above code returns an error.

How would I call the jQuery plugin as a method of the jQuery object; `$.key()` and not `$('#elem').key()`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Throws an error..

Comment: @hitautodestruct: _What_ error?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you try to get a plugin to work like in the question `$.keys(a);` without using the `$.extend` method then jquery throws an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.fn` is used when adding methods to be called on jQuery result objects.
For example, creating `$.fn.extend` would allow you to call something like `$('#some_el').extend()`.

To extend `$` instead, use `$.extend`:

```
$.extend({
        keys: function(obj) {
                var keys = [];
                $.each(obj, function(i, elem) {
                        keys.push(i);
                });

                return keys;
        }
});
```